# Scoping an Angular controller to a particular entity ID during initializaton

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of items displayed using a server-rendered template. Every item has a designated `ItemController` Angular controller. Certain user events cause methods on each controller instance to get called, delegating a remote call to the, obtaining the result and setting it back to the scope, to get it displayed.

Earlier, I simply used the `ItemController` scope as a view model, but the latest requirements specify a second view, outside of the list of items, that should also get the result from the server, and display it.

This means that I will have to create a service that would play the role of a shared model. I have the following question:

How can I initially tie a controller to a particular item ID from the beginning, so I could avoid passing it as a parameter all the time? Knowing the id at all times will also be needed for binding to the shared model.

Comment: can you provide your code? and html?

Comment: @Grundy check out this piece of code: http://plnkr.co/edit/wtcXNbsilw27sDHXseNL?p=preview There is currently no notion of an entity ID, and since I am trying to reuse the DetailsDataController from ItemController as well as outside of it, there must be a way to say "if I have been initialized with an ID parameter, check whether the latest selected item is relevant. If not, display it anyway"

Comment: can you explain your problem? i not quite understand what you expect.